# cakephp threaded comments

Tags: cakephp

I a bit new to cakephp and I'm wondering why I have this kind of problem.

Basically, I am doing a threaded comments in cakephp. But my problem is that every time I try to "comment" on a "comment", it is displaying differently.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I want it to be reversed like all the child comments should be posted on the last row. Currently, when I add a new comment, it is displayed on the top rather than on the bottom. I want it to become like how facebook does their commenting.

Here is my code for this:

```
$comments = $this->UserDiscussionComment->find('threaded', array('conditions' => array('UserDiscussionComment.user_discussion_id' => $slug), 'order' => array('UserDiscussionComment.id DESC', 'UserDiscussionComment.created ASC')));
```

And here is a sample records in the database:

[image]

I want to change the order of the child comments. I tried "ASC" and "DESC" but its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: array('UserDiscussionComment.id DESC', 'UserDiscussionComment.created ASC')

Comment: BTW, the multithreading tag is inappropriate for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to order the children in a different order according to the documentation for [find('threaded')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded). What I would do is after your find call, simply reverse the array:

```
$comments = $this->UserDiscussionComment->find('threaded', array(
    'conditions' => array('UserDiscussionComment.user_discussion_id' => $slug),
    'order' => array('UserDiscussionComment.id DESC')
));

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($comments); $i++) {
    $comments[$i]['children'] = array_reverse($comments[$i]['children']);
}
```

Untested but it should do the trick (also I assume you can only comment 1 level deep like your screenshot shows).

---

**Edit**

I wanted to share a different approach I used in the past for the same thing you're trying to accomplish. Basically I set my `Comment` model up like so:

```
class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ParentComment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        ),
        'User'
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'ChildComment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Then, when I want to do a find, I can order the parent & child comments differently (note that I'm using the `Containable` behavior):

```
$comments = $this->Comment->find('all', array(
    'order' => 'Comment.id DESC',
    'contain' => array(
        'ChildComment' => array(
            'order' => 'ChildComment.id ASC'
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: hi Hoff! Your solution is great! I was able to sort everything now. Thanks thanks thanks!

Comment: @comebal hello, If there is n number of reply like user A comment and user B reply on it and user C reply on user B reply like this. can you give me any solution or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
array('UserDiscussionComment.id DESC', 'UserDiscussionComment.created ASC')
```

I think the error is there.

As UserDiscussionComment.id are all distinct, there is nothing to order for `UserDiscussionComment.created ASC`.

Try:

```
array('UserDiscussionComment.parent_id DESC', 'UserDiscussionComment.created ASC')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But it is still showing me the wrong result after I applied your suggestion :(

Comment: And what does array('UserDiscussionComment.parent_id DESC', 'UserDiscussionComment.created DESC')  do?

Comment: It displays the child comments correctly but the main comments are inverted. The parent comments are being shown from oldest to newest, which should be the other way around... I really need your help. thanks in advance

Comment: Then do array('UserDiscussionComment.parent_id ASC', 'UserDiscussionComment.created DESC') if you want the other order. DESC gives from oldest to newest with dates.